# How can I correctly nest buttons in Streamlit with more than one Python function

Tags: python, streamlit

I have a basic script that allows users to compare 2 files and provide them with the differences between them. The Streamlit interface needs to export the final output file/comparison into Excel to the path specified by the user which is pasted into the text_input section titled "Enter the export path:". The code works fine up until the clicking of the "Export" button after which nothing happens and the results of the "Perform Comparison" are removed and that button needs to be clicked again.

Below is my script:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import streamlit as st

class Comparison:
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def compare(self, df_1, df_2):
        df_1 = pd.read_csv('file_1.txt', sep='|')
        df_1['Node Name'] = df_1['Node Name'].astype('string')

        df_2 = pd.read_csv('file_2.txt', sep='|')
        df_2['Node Name'] = df_2['Node Name'].astype('string')

        comparison_df = pd.merge(left=df_1, right=df_2, how='outer', on='Node Name', indicator=True, 
                            suffixes=['_prior', '_latest'])
        
        # Showing the number of Items that have been added in the latest file compared to the prior file.
        differences_df = comparison_df[comparison_df['_merge'] == 'right_only']

        return differences_df

    # Function to export the above file into excel.

    def export_func(self, differences_df, location):
        location = location.replace('\\', '/')
        differences_df.to_excel(f'{location}/differences_df_1.xlsx', index=False)
        print('File successfully saved!')





def main():

    st.set_page_config(page_title="Item daily comparison", page_icon=":chart_with_upwards_trend:", layout="wide")
    st.title("Item daily comparison")
    st.markdown("***")
    

    

    # Import prior file
    uploaded_file_prior = st.file_uploader("Upload your prior 'File' file", 
                                     type=["xlsx", "xls", "xlsb", "txt", "csv"])

    # Prior file
    if uploaded_file_prior is not None:
        df_prior = pd.read_csv(uploaded_file_prior)
        st.dataframe(df_prior)
        st.success("File successfully imported")

    # Import latest/current file
    uploaded_file_current = st.file_uploader("Upload your latest/current 'File' file", 
                                     type=["xlsx", "xls", "xlsb", "txt", "csv"])

    # Latest/current file
    if uploaded_file_current is not None:
        df_current = pd.read_csv(uploaded_file_current)
        st.dataframe(df_current)
        st.success("File successfully imported")

    # Perform comparison between the 2 files.
    if st.button("Perform Comparison"):
        final_compare = Comparison()
        df_compared = final_compare.compare(df_1= df_prior, df_2= df_current)
        st.dataframe(df_compared)
        st.write(f'Total number of differences: {df_compared["Node Name"].count()}')

    # View the output file with only differences before exporting into Excel.
    if st.button("Click to export output file"):
        location = st.text_input("Enter the export path:")
        st.write("Test 1")

        # Execute the button only if there is a path pasted in the input section above.
        if st.button("Export") and location:
            st.write("Test 2")
            final_compare.export_func(differences_df=df_compared, location=location)
            st.success("File successfully exported!")



if __name__== "__main__":
    main()
```

I have a feeling the issue is a nesting one but I have tried every possible combination of this and nothing works. I tried having the "Export" button to not be nested under the "Enter the export path" but then that causes the error of "location is specified before assignment" which makes sense.

Location variable has been defined to be easy for the user to copy/paste straight from their windows explorer path and not have to change the backslashes to forward slashes "/".

I am aware that Streamlit has an export button already built-in over the dataframe created from "df_compared" but my concern is understanding the principle of why this is happening and not simply getting to the answer.

Comment: You should read and understand [this streamlit button](https://docs.streamlit.io/library/advanced-features/button-behavior-and-examples)